# SQLite date string comparison. SAME FORMAT not working

Tags: string, sqlite, date, format, comparison

Please Help! This has been driving me nuts. YES I have looked at dozens of Stack Overflow answers for similar questions, and they all say "Your dates should be in a consistent accepted format".

**All** of my SQLite dates are stored in the following string format:

```
'yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss'
```

I'm trying to do date comparison but NOTHING works. For instance:

```
SELECT         transactiondate
FROM           transactions 
WHERE          transactiondate >= '2010-02-19 00:00:00'
```

Doesn't work.. I get 0 records returned.

Even though when I run it without the WHERE clause I get returned date strings like:

```
'2017-02-25 00:00:00'
```

In fact, simply doing:

```
SELECT         transactiondate
FROM           transactions 
WHERE          '2017-02-25 00:00:00' >= '2010-02-19 00:00:00'
```

Does work, i.e. it compares the dates successfully in its raw form but not when referring to the table column value.

**PLEASE..** WTF am I doing wrong?

Also, I've tried every permutation of datetime(...), date(...) in the SQL to no avail. I have also tried using ... BETWEEN ... AND ..., it doesn't help.

Thanks in advance if anyone can figure this out.

Comment: select distinct length(transactiondate) from transactions; to check for invisible chars. Check if space is really a tab. I use sqlite for such datetime things myself, althoug my format is yyyymmdd-hh:mi:ss.

Comment: Hi, I get 1 result: 

length(transactiondate)
21

Comment: Which is different than 19. The invisible chars theory just got stronger. Is it newline chars? exstra spaces? Maybe the data can be repaired with UPDATE and SUBSTR.

Comment: but length of "'2010-02-19 00:00:00'" is 21, including the single quotes

Comment: As a diagnostic, try using the `date` function to convert some of the values stored in the table to an 'internal' representation and then back again to 'see what happens'?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You got the ' in the front and end included in your data. In column transactiondate.

Then you also need to include ' chars in your WHERE filter too. Two ways to do that in SQLite:

```
select * from transactions where transactiondate >= "'2010-02-19 00:00:00'";
select * from transactions where transactiondate >= '''2010-02-19 00:00:00''';
```

However, I suggest you clean up your data instead:

```
update transactions
set transactiondate=substr(transactiondate,2,length(transactiondate)-2)
where transactiondate like "'%'";
```

Now you can use your original WHERE without the extra ' chars.

Comment: Oooh I see, I didn't realise that the single quotes were part of the data, I figured this was an indication that it is a string value! Thanks so much, +1'd :)

I worked with T-SQL and VB web services for a year, hence my assumption (this sort of comparison always worked before).

Answer (score 0):

OK, This is not an answer. But in SO you can't do this kind of thing in a comment.

I can't replicate the condition you have. The code, in particular the SELECT, works well enough executed from Python.

```
>>> import sqlite3
>>> conn = sqlite3.connect(':memory:')
>>> cur = conn.cursor()
>>> cur.execute('CREATE TABLE transactions (transactionsdate string)')
<sqlite3.Cursor object at 0x000000000531CCE0>
>>> cur.execute('''INSERT INTO transactions VALUES ('2010-02-10 00:00:00')''')
<sqlite3.Cursor object at 0x000000000531CCE0>
>>> cur.execute('''INSERT INTO transactions VALUES ('2017-02-10 00:00:00')''')
<sqlite3.Cursor object at 0x000000000531CCE0>
>>> list(cur.execute("SELECT * from transactions where transactionsdate >= '2010-02-19 00:00:00'"))
[('2017-02-10 00:00:00',)]
>>> list(cur.execute("SELECT * from transactions"))
[('2010-02-10 00:00:00',), ('2017-02-10 00:00:00',)]
```

Stab in the dark: Can you dump the contents of the field into a text file and examine it using (say) Notepad++, which would enable to to see non-printing characters that are interfering?

Comment: Hi, when I export as CSV and open in NotePad++ the transactiondate comes out as "'2017-02-18 00:00:00'", which is kind of what I expected

Comment: As I said, shot in the dark. (You did have `View | Show Symbols | Show All Characters` checked?)

Comment: Yes, I did , definitely just '2017-02-18 00:00:00' in the notepad++ window

Comment: OK, I give up. :)